# Android login and storing with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner in android coding. And, I want to create a login page for my application. Am using Firebase as my back end server. Using Authentication services provided by Firebase am able to create user successfully. But, as we know, user must input login credentials at the time of application installation. So, any one suggest me how to develop this part in android where it takes credentials on app installation and store them locally so that user need not enter credentials all the time he launched application.
Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` to track user login state . follow -> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat try this github code.....

Comment: try this.... https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to store your user information locally. But I think in your case using `SharedPreference` will be best solution.

I assume you have initialized all related stuff with `FireBase` , then first we need to check if our user **is logged before** or not . To check it we will use `SharedPreferences`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    // other setup code
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (mPrefs.getBoolean("is_logged_before",false)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        // continue to login part
    }
}
```

Then you should save your user informations to `SharedPreferences` , if you registered/logged-in succesfully to `FireBase`. There should be `onSuccess` function at FireBase, for listening result of your login request. So just save the user informations and other related informations here locally to `SharedPreferences`.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
    System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
    mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("userId", result.get("uid"));
    editor.putBoolean("is_logged_before",true); //this line will do trick
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firebase already persists the session (in SharedPreferences) token when the user signs in, so you don't have to do that yourself.

Instead you should [monitor whether the user is logged in](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication). From that documentation:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
        if (authData != null) {
            // user is logged in
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    }
});
```